# jQuery function to count characters in textarea is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

The below code is used to count characters in a `textarea`. The problem is, when I press "enter" (while focused on the `textarea`) the remaining characters are displayed but the `textarea` limit is over. Can someone help me with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text_max = 99;
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

  $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<p id="textarea_feedback"></p>
```

Comment: make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

***Try This***

this function count up to limit and it will not allow to enter another characters extra

it just remove the extra characters.

```js
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;
  var text_max = 99;

  if (len >= text_max) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, text_max);
    $('#textarea_feedback').text(((text_max - len) + 1) + ' characters remaining - out of limit');
  } else {
    $('#textarea_feedback').text((text_max - len) + ' characters remaining');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="50" rows="8" id="field" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback">99 characters remaining</div>
```

Comment: Press and hold "enter" continuously, your character remaining count drops below 0. It corrects itself on the next keypress, but its a bit buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/jhacqgkd/),

**Updated javascript**

```
$(function(){
    var text_max = 99;
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');
  $("#textarea").keyup(function(){
      var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
      var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
     $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="textarea_feedback"></span>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be help u

```
function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e, length) {
    mLen = length;
    var maxLength = parseInt(mLen);
    if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
        if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1) {
            if (window.event)//IE
                e.returnValue = false;
            else//Firefox
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}

function MinCharactorTextarea(textBox, e, MaxLength) {
    var tval = $(textBox).val();
    var tlength = tval.length;
    var lblMax = $(textBox).next();
    var text = tlength + " / " + MaxLength + " max";
    $(lblMax).text(text);
}
```

in ASP textbox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" TextMode="MultiLine"   MaxLength="80" onkeydown="checkTextAreaMaxLength(this,event,'80');" onkeyup="MinCharactorTextarea(this,event,80);">
```

0 / 80 max

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Solution, i think it is help you

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var max = 99;
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(max + ' characters remaining');
  $('textarea.max').keypress(function(e) {
    var text_remaining = max - this.value.length;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    $("p").html("");
    if (e.which < 0x20) {
      // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
      // e.which === 0 - Not a character
      return; // Do nothing
    }
    if (this.value.length == max) {
      $("p").html("out Of Limit");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else if (this.value.length > max) {
      // Maximum exceeded     
      this.value.substring(0, max);   
    }
  });
}); //end if ready(fn)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="textarea_feedback"></span>
<textarea class="max"></textarea>
<p> </p>
```

Comment: Keep pressing "enter" indefinitely and you get minus characters (tested in chrome) once you are below 0. You can continue typing as normal. Not a good solution.